# XSLT transforming XML with language translation for ticket printing

Tags: xml, xslt, printing

I would like to translate my ticket (for printing) by using XSLT and transforming an existing XML file.

part of XML:

```
<description>.Kleine Wrap</description>
    <description-translations>
      <translation lang="fr">.Petite Galette</translation>
      <translation lang="nl">.Kleine Wrap</translation>
      <translation lang="en">.Small Wrap</translation>
    </description-translations>
```

XSLT line:

`<xsl:value-of select="description-translations"/>`  --> If I do this, it prints out ALL 3 translations from the XML file.

[ticket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LtZX.png)

Does anyone know how I can select the specific language by using fr, nl and en?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `description-translations/translation[@lang=$required-lang]` where $required-lang is the language you require.

If you used the standard `xml:lang` attribute rather than `lang` as your attribute name, then you would be able to use the `lang()` function which gives more capability for selecting language variants, e.g. en-GB vs en-US.

Comment: You wouldn't believe it but I figured this out a couple of minutes ago myself! Anyway, thank you very much for your answer! This worked.
For the lang() function: I don't think I can really use this since everything is custom made for a POS system but will keep it in mind, thanks!

Comment: I have no difficulty believing it, what I find more difficult to understand is that you didn't figure it out before posting the question. It suggests to me that investing a few hours in reading about the language would save you a lot of time as you start using it more seriously.